# Swift disable hidden property for UIImageView in Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am using Swift 2 with XCode 7 beta. I am rendering UICollectionView with Cells that have image and label in it. Image should be hidden at the time of viewLoad.

This is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    cell.contactName.text = contactsNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectedIcon.hidden = true

    return cell
}

// selection of the item
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    cell.selectedIcon.hidden = false
}
```

I have also tried during loading to put in first collectionView method `cell.selectedIcon.hidden = true`, which showed the items. But still interaction didn't work (when I click on the item, it didn't show).

Can you advice how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all read this about the [`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:) method:

> Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the collection view. This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.

To access to one specific cell there are severals options you can use but in your specific case I think the method [`cellForItemAtIndexPath(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:)(this method is not the same you use to set the initial values for the cells, like you put above) is the best choice, like in the following way:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ContactCell
   cell.selectedIcon.hidden = false
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload data in your selection of item function.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactCell
   cell.selectedIcon.hidden = false
   collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Can you advice how to do this? I tried this: `collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])` and         `collectionView.reloadData()` and both not working.

Comment: Do you have a collectionCell ? Try to put your function in this file

Comment: I updated my comment. I used collectionView that is parameter in collectionView method

Comment: You can do a function to reload your collectionView and call it when you select your item.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same function but for tvOS, i think it will work for iOS too. give it a try , maybe it works.

This is the Code:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let prev = context.previouslyFocusedView as? ContactCell {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            prev.selectedIcon.hidden = true            
        })
    }

    if let next = context.nextFocusedView as? ContactCell{
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            next.selectedIcon.hidden = false            
        })
    }
}
```